# Magento 2.2 Enable ImageMagick Linux Centos 7

Tags: magento2, php, apache

I am trying to change image adapter in my Magento 2.2.2 store from GD2 to

I am doing this

1. Run this is CLI 
   /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/pecl install imagick
2. Run this in CLI change to and enable ImageMagick  in Magento 2
   ImageMagick

php bin/magento config:set dev/image/default_adapter imagick

But I get this error

The specified image adapter cannot be used because of: Image adapter for 'imagick' is not setup.

Please can someone help

Comment: what's the output of running #1

Comment: install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/imagick-3.4.4  is this the correct version for magento 2.2.2

Comment: Does `php bin/magento config:set dev/image/default_adapter IMAGEMAGICK` work (or ImageMagick)

Comment: php bin/magento config:set dev/image/default_adapter IMAGEMAGICK   gives output  vlaue was saved  - is this correct? anyway to test which adapter magento is now using?

Comment: Yes this has an image adapter built-in: \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\ImageMagick.  Not sure how to verify it gets used without directly editing the class or stepping through the code.

Comment: In admin you can visit stores -> configuration -> developer -> image processing settings and verify it's set to ImageMagick

Comment: thank but this option is no longer available on magento 2.2 and I can not find it in that location either hence trying it via CLI

Comment: I believe developer mode needs to be enabled to see stores -> configuration -> developer